# Switch statement with strings?

Tags: c

I'm working on a small homework assignment and I'm supposed to make a food menu. Anyways, my switch isn't working. I'm trying to use a simple function that I can pass a value of "fish", "drink", or "chips" to and then it will output:

```
"Are you ordering FISH?" (or chips/drink)
```

I can't get the switch to work, it's supposed to detect what I pass into it and then output a printf based on the switch case.

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void menu() {
    printf("\nWelcome to Sunny FISH & CHIPS!\n\n");
    printf("########     Fish :     Haddock(K) Large(L) | $5.00\n");
    printf("# FOOD #                Halibut(T) Large(L) | $4.00\n");
    printf("########     Chips:     Cut(C)     Large(L) | $2.00\n");
    printf("                        Ring(R)    Large(L) | $3.00\n");
    printf("                                            | \n");
    printf("##########   Soft Drinks(S)        Large(L) | $2.00\n");
    printf("# DRINKS #   Coffee(C)             Large(L) | $1.75\n");
    printf("##########   Tea(T)                Large(L) | $1.50\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Note: Medium price: 80%% of large.\n");
    printf("       Small price: 60%% of large.\n");
    printf("TAX is 10%%.\n");
    printf("More than 5 fish, 10%% discount on drink.\n");
    printf("Every 10 fish purchased, get 1 free softdrink.\n");
    printf("  - size of drink is according to size of fish\n");
}

void question (char choice[5]) {
    switch (choice[5]) 
    {
        case choice["fish"]:
            printf("Do you order FISH?\n");
        case choice["drink"]:
            printf("Do you order CHIPS?\n");
        case choice["chips"] :
            printf("Do you order DRINKS?\n");
        default :
            printf("Enter a valid choice: \n");
    }
}

main() {

    // menu();
    question("fish");

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, if you find that your list of choices all begin with a unique letter (or have a unique letter in another position) then you can `switch` on that letter:

```
switch (choice[0]) {
case 'f':
    // they chose fish
    break;
case 'c':
    // they chose chips
    break;
case 'd':
    // they chose drink
}
```

This will be faster than using `strcmp` (although it doesn't matter for your case) and is less maintainable. However, it's good to know all the options and realise how you can use some of these things.

Comment: Inside each case, you should use `strcmp` to make sure the full string actually matches.

Comment: @R.. As I said, this will only work properly if each choice has a unique letter in some position.

Comment: That's a separate issue. My point is that your solution will also accept other strings that begin with the same letter but which are not in the list.

Comment: @R.. yes that is true, my answer presupposed that the input was valid.

Comment: Yes. And my purpose in commenting was to point out that your answer is still good even if you can't presuppose that, as long as you add `strcmp` checks in the cases (it's still more efficient than a linear search of the valid responses with a `strcmp` against each).

Comment: @R.. feel free to edit my answer if you have the time, I will add something about what you said in a while if you don't.

Answer (score 10):

C **does not** support that kind of switch, but **if** it would, the syntax **would** be

```
 switch(choice)
 {
    case "fish":
        something();
        break;
    case "drink":
        other_thing();
        break;
 }
```

A switch to me is often clearer than a (long) list of if - else ifs. Even though **in this case** it seems overcomplicated, I **would** prefer approaches like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum menu_items { FISH, DRINK, CHIPS, UNKNOWN };

struct items
{
  char *name;
  enum menu_items id;
} items_list[] = {
  { "fish", FISH },
  { "drink", DRINK },
  { "chips", CHIPS }
};

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  enum menu_items mid;
  struct items *choice = NULL;

  // ...

  for(i = 0, choice = NULL; i < sizeof items_list/sizeof (struct items); i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(answer, items_list[i].name) == 0)
    {
      choice = items_list + i;
      break;
    }
  }    

  mid = choice ? choice->id : UNKNOWN;

  // the following would be enough to obtain the output of your example;
  // I've not embodied the code into a func, but it's easy to do if you need
  if ( mid != UNKNOWN )
  {
      // the function a_func transforms the string of the food
      // e.g. to uppercase, or it could map it to whatever according to some
      // other data... or expand the struct to hold what you want to output
      // with "fish", "drink", "chips", e.g. choice->screen_name
      printf("Do you order %s?\n", a_func(choice->name));
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Enter a valid choice:\n");
  }
  // ---------

  // or if you prefer the switch you have something like:

  switch(mid)
  {
  case FISH:
    printf("fish\n");
    break;
  case DRINK:
    printf("drink\n");
    break;
  case CHIPS:
    printf("chips\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("unknown choice\n");
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you choose properly the approach, your code could be always the same and only your data grow.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `switch` statement with strings.

You may consider using `strcmp` to compare strings.

```
if (strcmp(choice,"fish")==0) {
     //fish
} 
else if (strcmp(choice,"drink")==0) {
     //drink
}
. 
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't support switches on strings...you should use `strcmp()`

Answer (score 1):

`switch` doesn't work like that in C.  You'll need to make an `if` statement construct and use `strcmp()` to compare the strings.